# Create a batch project with game

Tags: batch, code

I have a batch file for installing a game and changing the language.

**ISO file**

ISO [virtual drive mounted] (can be any letter D:\ E:\ F:\ etc...)

- AutoRun.inf (this run the .bat and .ico)
- Run.bat (this has the code for install and open the language)
- Game.exe

**Run.bat:**

```
@echo off
Start /wait Game.exe
Start /wait "C:\Game path\language_setup.exe"
```

The problem is the third line won't execute or open `language_setup.exe`.
I try with `"` and without `"`, with `cd C:`, and many others commands.
Can anyone help me to launch "languague_setup.exe" in C:\ from the letter "X:\" of the virtual ISO please?

Comment: is c:\game path\language_setup.exe the actual path to the .exe?

Comment: yes its is, after install (first Start /wait) the file its in C: drive, then i need open that file in C:\ from X:\ (D: E: F: etc... any letter)

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax for the third line:

```
Start /wait "title" "C:\Game path\language_setup.exe"
```

The Start command thinks the path to your exe is a title for the window you're opening. You have to supply a faux title so that Start properly interprets the following parameter as the full pathname of the executable you want to run.

Comment: i solved with this:

`@echo off

Start /Wait game.exe
Language_setup.lnk

exit`

But now i want to delete a .lnk from desktop or replace and i can't do it, can you help me please?
another thing, how can you post the code in that way?

Comment: I have no idea what that command is supposed to do nor how it could possibly solve your problem. You're not even executing the `language_setup.exe` command shown in your OP. As for your second question, please Ask a new question. It's not good form to ask for additional answers in the comments.